# How to clone two-dimensional List?

Tags: java, list

I want to clone list:

```
public List<List<Test>> a = new ArrayList<List<Test>>();
public List<List<Test>> b = new ArrayList<List<Test>>();
```

But if I do:

```
b = (ArrayList<List<Test>>)a.clone();
```

Occurs an error:

```
The method clone() is undefined for the type List<List<Test>>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You must override clone() from Object. A related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.List` does not implement `Cloneable`, so the compiler cannot ensure that the concrete implementation you are using does. So, it won't allow you to write a code that calls a method that may not be there.

If you know the concrete implementation, you can cast it. V.g., if it is an `ArrayList<List<Test>>` (since `ArrayList` does implement `Cloneable`), then you do

```
  b = (List<List<Test>>) ((ArrayList<List<Test>>) a).clone();
```

If you do not, implement your own method.

Remember that the default `clone` makes shallow copies. That is, the object returned will be a new `List<List<Test>>`, but the inner `List<Test>` and `Test` will not get copied and you will get references to the original objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `clone()` is not available for the abstract list, only for `ArrayList`. However it will not work as you expect as it only returns a shallow copy. To make a deep copy, you need to clone in a loop:

```
   for (List<Test> item: a)
      b.add(new ArrayList(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor or the `addAll` method:

```
new ArrayList<>(a);
//or
b.addAll(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can create a new list using the same objects as the previous one simply using streams:

```
List<Double> secondList = firstList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a new list that doesn't share the same objects with the first one, you can do this (supposing your objects implements `Cloneable`):

If you're using Java 8, you can create a new list using the same objects as the previous one simply using streams:

```
List<Double> secondList = firstList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a new list that doesn't share the same objects with the first one, you can do this (supposing your objects implements `Cloneable`):

```
List<Double> secondList = firstList.stream().map(v -> v.clone()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```